# Bottom-Up-Parser: When to apply which reduction rule?

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, bottom-up

Let's take the following context-free grammar:

```
G = ( {Sum, Product, Number}, {decimal representations of numbers, +, *}, P, Sum)
```

Being P:

```
Sum → Sum + Product
Sum → Product
Product → Product * Number
Product → Number
Number → decimal representation of a number
```

I am trying to parse expressions produced by this grammar with a bottom-up-parser and a look-ahead-buffer (LAB) of length 1 (which supposingly should do without guessing and back-tracking).

Now, given a stack and a LAB, there are often several possibilities of how to reduce the stack or whether to reduce it at all or push another token.

Currently I use this decision tree:

> If any top n tokens of the stack plus the LAB are the begining of the
>   right side of a rule, I push the next token onto the stack.
>
> Otherwise, I reduce the maximum number of tokens on top of the stack.
>   I.e. if it is possible to reduce the topmost item and at the same time
>   it is possible to reduce the three top most items, I do the latter.
>
> If no such reduction is possible, I push another token onto the stack.
>
> Rinse and repeat.

This, seems (!) to work, **but** it requires an awful amount of rule searching, finding matching prefixes, etc. No way this can run in O(NM).

**What is the standard (and possibly only sensible) approach to decide whether to reduce or push (shift), and in case of reduction, which reduction to apply?**

Thank you in advance for your comments and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest bottom-up parsing approach for grammars like yours (basically, expression grammars) is operator-precedence parsing.

Recall that bottom-up parsing involves building the parse tree left-to-right from the bottom. In other words, at any given time during the parse, we have a partially assembled tree with only terminal symbols to the right of where we're reading, and a combination of terminals and non-terminals to the left (the "prefix"). The only possible reduction is one which applies to a suffix of the prefix; if no reduction applies, we must be able to shift a terminal from the input to the prefix.

An operator grammar has the feature that there are never two consecutive non-terminals in any production. Consequently, in a bottom-up parse of an operator grammar, either the last symbol in the prefix is a terminal or the second-last symbol is one. (Both of them could be.)

An operator precedence parser is essentially blind to non-terminals; it simply doesn't distinguish between them. So you cannot have two productions whose right-hand sides contain exactly the same sequence of terminals, because the op-prec parser wouldn't know which of these two productions to apply. (That's the traditional view. It's actually possible to extend that a bit so that you can have two productions with the same terminals, provided that the non-terminals are in different places. That allows grammars which have unary `-` operators, for example, since the right hand sides `<non-terminal> - <non-terminal>` and `- <non-terminal>` can be distinguished without knowing the names of the non-terminals; only their presence.

The other requirement is that you have to be able to build a precedence relationship between the terminals. More precisely, we define three precedence relations, usually written `<·`, `·>` and `·=·` (or some typographic variation on the theme), and insist that for any two terminals `x` and `y`, at most one of the relations `x ·> y`, `x ·=· y` and `x <· y` are true.

Roughly speaking, the `<` and `>` in the relations correspond to the edges of a production. In other words, if `x <· y`, that means that `x` can be followed by a non-terminal with a production whose first terminal is `y`. Similarly, `x ·> y` means that `y` can follow a non-terminal with a production whose last terminal is `x`. And `x ·=· y` means that there is some right-hand side where `x` and `y` are consecutive terminals, in that order (possibly with an intervening non-terminal).

If the single-relation restriction is true, then we can parse as follows:

> Let `x` be the last terminal in the prefix (that is, either the last or second-last symbol), and let `y` be the lookahead symbol, which must be a terminal. If `x ·> y` then we reduce, and repeat the rule. Otherwise, we shift `y` onto the prefix.

In order to reduce, we need to find the start of the production. We move backwards over the prefix, comparing consecutive terminals (all of which must have `<·` or `·=·` relations) until we find one with a `<·` relation. Then the terminals between the `<·` and the `·>` are the right-hand side of the production we're looking for, and we can slot the non-terminals into the right-hand side as indicated.

There is no guarantee that there will be an appropriate production; if there isn't, the parse fails. But if the input is a valid sentence, and if the grammar is an operator-precedence grammar, then we will be able to find the right production to reduce.

Note that it is usually really easy to find the production, because most productions have only one (`<non-terminal> * <non-terminal>`) or two (`( <non-terminal> )`) terminals. A naive implementation might just run the terminals together into a string and use that as the key in a hash-table.

The classic implementation of operator-precedence parsing is the so-called "Shunting Yard Algorithm", devised by Edsger Dijkstra. In that algorithm, the precedence relations are modelled by providing two functions, left-precedence and right-precedence, which map terminals to integers such that `x <· y` is true only if `right-precedence(x) < left-precedence(y)` (and similarly for the other operators). It is not always possible to find such mappings, and the mappings are a cover of the actual precedence relations because it is often the case that there are pairs of terminals for which no precedence relationship applies. Nonetheless, it is often the case that these mappings can be found, and almost always the case for simple expression grammars.

I hope that's enough to get you started. I encourage you to actually read some texts about bottom-up parsing, because I think I've already written far too much for an SO answer, and I haven't yet included a single line of code. :)

Comment: Thank you rici. Let me digest your answer.

Comment: Is this approach also applicable for the grammar in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797248/cfg-for-python-style-tuples? I fear not due to `TupleItem → TupleItem TupleItem`...

Comment: @Hyperboreus: I answered your other question with an operator grammar. Op-prec parsing can actually deal with regular-expression RHS's directly, and a very simple op-prec parser could be built for the tuple grammar.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, carnal.

Comment: In the grammar I gave in my question, which relation (`<·`, `·=·`, `·>`) is there between the terminals `decimal` and `+`, and between `+` and `decimal`? If I read it correctly none at all.

Comment: `+ <· decimal` and `decimal ·> +` because `decimal` can be the first terminal and the last terminal, respectively, of `Number`. Terminals like `decimal` which only appear as unit-productions can be handled in an expedited fashion, as per the original shunting-yard algorithm, but they work fine with the full algorithm too.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: There's a formal definition and a worked example very similar to your grammar on the bottom of page 2 and the top of page 3 of this paper: http://home.deib.polimi.it/pradella/papers/floydpar.pdf. Note that the definition of Lg and Rg involves =>*, not just =>.